# Trying to achieve CSS code with LESS

Tags: css, less

I want to generate this CSS code with LESS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

But currently I'm generating this CSS code with LESS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Here is my LESS code:

```
.navbar-default {
//& always refers to the current selector.  
    .navbar-nav {
        & >.active {
            & > a {
                background-color: blue !important;

                &:focus {
                    background-color: blue !important;
                }
                &:hover {
                    background-color: blue !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
.navbar-default {  
    .navbar-nav {
        & >.active {
            & > a {
                &, &:focus, &:hover {
                    background-color: blue !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify it to this, though:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav >.active > a {
  &, &:focus, &:hover {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }
}
```

Both of which will output the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Ah I understand, I should have used the commas. Thank you very much for your answer :)